# Angular - Failed to compile with not assignable error when creating a new interface

Tags: angular

I am creating a simple new interface and getting a compile error, any suggestion what I did wrong here

Here's my error:

C:/Users/vashon/Angular/Angular-GettingStarted-master/APM/src/app/products/product-list.component.ts (16,2): Type '{ "productId": number; "productName": string; "productCode": string; "releaseDate": string; "desc...' is not assignable to type 'IProduct[]'.
  Type '{ "productId": number; "productName": string; "productCode": string; "releaseDate": string; "desc...' is not assignable to type 'IProduct'.
    Types of property 'releaseDate' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Date'.

My product.ts interface

```
export interface IProduct {

 productId: number;
 productName: string;
 productCode: string;
 releaseDate: string;
 description: string;
 price: number;
 starRating: number;
 imageUrl: string;
}
```

My product-list.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IProduct } from './product';

@Component ({
    selector: 'pm-products',
    templateUrl: './product-list.component.html'    
}
)

export class ProductListComponent {
    pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
    imageWidth: number = 50;
    imageMargin: number = 2;
    showImage: boolean = false;
    listFilter: string = 'carts';
    products: IProduct[] = [
    {
        "productId": 1,
        "productName": "Leaf Rake",
        "productCode": "GDN-0011",
        "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
        "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
        "price": 19.95,
        "starRating": 3.2,
        "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
    },
    {
        "productId": 2,
        "productName": "Garden Cart",
        "productCode": "GDN-0023",
        "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
        "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
        "price": 32.99,
        "starRating": 4.2,
        "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
    }];

    toggleImage() : void {
        this.showImage = !this.showImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is unclear in the error message? Have you at least read it? Note that the actual code is not the one you posted, according to the error message. So you probably forgot to save your changes.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I read the error message.  It looks like it couldn't find my IProduct but I have it there in the product.ts file.  And yes, it was saved.  This is actual code.  Thanks for replying.

Comment: It does find the interface. Read the error message. It says that you're trying to assign an array of objects with a releaseDate field of type String to a variable type IProduct[] whose elements should have a releaseDate of type **Date**. Given that the code you posted define the field releaseDate as a string, the error doesn't match the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

```
export class AppComponent {

  arr = new ProductListComponent();
  constructor(){
    console.log(this.arr.products[0]);
  }
}

export interface IProduct {

  productId: number;
  productName: string;
  productCode: string;
  releaseDate: string;
  description: string;
  price: number;
  starRating: number;
  imageUrl: string;
}

export class ProductListComponent {
  pageTitle: string = 'Product List';
  imageWidth: number = 50;
  imageMargin: number = 2;
  showImage: boolean = false;
  listFilter: string = 'carts';
  products: Array<IProduct> = [
    {
      "productId": 1,
      "productName": "Leaf Rake",
      "productCode": "GDN-0011",
      "releaseDate": "March 19, 2016",
      "description": "Leaf rake with 48-inch wooden handle.",
      "price": 19.95,
      "starRating": 3.2,
      "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/26215/Anonymous_Leaf_Rake.png"
    },
    {
      "productId": 2,
      "productName": "Garden Cart",
      "productCode": "GDN-0023",
      "releaseDate": "March 18, 2016",
      "description": "15 gallon capacity rolling garden cart",
      "price": 32.99,
      "starRating": 4.2,
      "imageUrl": "http://openclipart.org/image/300px/svg_to_png/58471/garden_cart.png"
    }];

  toggleImage(): void {
    this.showImage = !this.showImage;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all property types match with interface vs JSON. When everything correct and you still see error specific to Type matching issues with interface during compile. Just restart VSCode it works fine.